# Align a double line chart and a bar plot on the x axis when both charts have the same X axis. ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I have been attempting this for quite sometime today and still haven't been able to align two different chart types together by their X axis which are the same. I simply need a double line chart on top of a bar chart when both charts have the same X axis.

My data below is below along with the code I have written so far and with a few different attempts.

My data:

```
Date <- c("2015-07-22", "2015-07-23", "2015-07-24", "2015-07-25", "2015-07-26", "2015-07-27", "2015-07-28", "2015-07-29", "2015-07-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-08-01", "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03", "2015-08-04", "2015-08-05")

Mean_temp12z <- c(66.6, 64.6, 67.6, 69.6, 72.0, 71.8, 73.0, 72.2, 72.8, 71.8, 69.4, 64.2, 61.2, 62.0, 63.4)

Mean_temp0z <- c(62.8, 65.0, 67.4, 71.6, 72.4, 71.6, 71.0, 71.8, 71.6, 69.6, 69.2, 66.2, 60.6, 63.6, 66.4)  

temp_deltalow <- c( 3.8, -0.4,  0.2, -2.0, -0.4,  0.2,  2.0,  0.4,  1.2,  2.2,  0.2, -2.0,  0.6, -1.6, -3.0)


GFS_low_changes <- data.frame(Date, Mean_temp12z, Mean_temp0z, temp_deltalow)
```

What I have plotted so far is a double line chart shown with this code and image below:

```
low_line <- ggplot(GFS_low_changes, aes(Date))+ geom_line(aes(y= Mean_temp12z, colour= "Mean_temp12z" ))+ geom_line(aes(y= Mean_temp0z, colour= "Mean_temp0z"))+
  geom_point(aes(y= Mean_temp12z))+ geom_point(aes(y= Mean_temp0z))+
  theme(legend.title= element_text(colour="black", size=12))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="GFS Models")+ labs(y= "Temperature °F")
```

[image: double line chart]

I have also plotted a bar chart showing the delta between the 0z model and 12z model shown with the code and image below:

```
low_bar <- ggplot(data = GFS_low_changes, aes(x= Date, y = temp_deltalow)) + 
  geom_bar(colour= "black", fill= ifelse(temp_deltalow>0,"red","blue"), stat= "identity", position = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(temp_deltalow, "°F"),hjust= 0.4, vjust= ifelse(temp_deltalow>0,-0.5,1)), size= 5)
```

[image: bar plot]

So with both of these graphs created, I would like to merge them on the X axis with the line chart on top of the bar chart. Seamless spacing between the two is preferable, but I have not been able to get them close to lining up.

I've attempted using the `grid.draw` function from the gridExtra package with the code:

```
  grid.newpage() 
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(low_line), ggplotGrob(low_bar), recording= T))
```

but I get an error telling me:  Error: ncol(x) == ncol(y) is not TRUE

I've also used `grid.arrange` which gets me better results, but no where close to the same x axis and seamless integration between the two charts.

I want to avoid running on here, but I did attempt melting the data frame above and was only able to plot the line charts successfully. But any help in this area is also much appreciated.

I was mainly running off this example during my attempts: https://gist.github.com/tomhopper/faa24797bb44addeba79

Any help with this issue is much appreciated!

Comment: maybe `facet` could be an alternative?

Comment: @mts it's very difficult to get facets to work when you have different geoms for different graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will align the x-axis and fix the layout.  However, there is still spacing between the figures.

```
## Specify the xlimits
xlims <- as.Date(c("2015-07-21", "2015-08-06"))

## low_bar as you had it, except the ylimits are adjusted for labels and xlims added
low_bar <- ggplot(data = GFS_low_changes, aes(x= Date, y = temp_deltalow)) + 
  geom_bar(colour= "black", fill= ifelse(temp_deltalow>0,"red","blue"), stat= "identity", position = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(temp_deltalow, "°F"),hjust= 0.4, vjust= ifelse(temp_deltalow>0,-0.5,1)), size= 5) +
  ylim(-4, 5) +
  xlim(xlims)

## low_line, legend is changed and xlims is added
low_line <- ggplot(GFS_low_changes, aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= Mean_temp12z, colour= "Mean_temp12z" )) +
  geom_line(aes(y= Mean_temp0z, colour= "Mean_temp0z"))+
  geom_point(aes(y= Mean_temp12z))+
  geom_point(aes(y= Mean_temp0z))+
  theme(legend.title= element_text(colour="black", size=12))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="GFS Models")+ labs(y= "Temperature °F") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9,0.8)) +
  xlim(xlims)

## Construct the layout, 2 rows one column
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 1)))
print(low_bar, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col=1))
print(low_line, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col=1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, although I was hoping to merge them by the X axis, this should work just fine. Thank you for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

you could use `combine()` from gridExtra (modified version of gtable::join),

```
library(gridExtra)

g1 <- ggplotGrob(low_line)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(low_bar)
colnames(g1) <- paste0(seq_len(ncol(g1)))
colnames(g2) <- paste0(seq_len(ncol(g2)))

grid.draw(combine(g1, g2, along=2))
```

the same result can be obtained with `gtable`, but it's less convenient because i) `join` had bugs (dev version is fixed), ii) rbind doesn't like to compare units with `unit.pmax`. That's why I've duplicated those functions in gridExtra for now.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the response. I do like the layout here, but having the dots on the first graph remain color coded would be ideal. I'll poke around with your solution more to see if that's a possibility. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe `join` is called `combine` now.